# Error when work with Moodle 3.2.2 Authentication external DB via Oracle

Tags: php, database, debugging, moodle, salt

I was trying to set up the external authentication for Moodle, here are my settings(db_enabled.png), and I tested it and all normal(test_enabled.png), test proceed normally, but when I try to login with the account from the external database, I have this error(result_error.png).
Error:

```
Could not connect to the specified authentication database...
line 118 of /auth/db/auth.php: call to debugging()
line 4303 of /lib/moodlelib.php: call to auth_plugin_db->user_login()
line 154 of /login/index.php: call to authenticate_user_login()
```

My question is, this error is about the database, but the database test is normal, could you please help me?
P.S: Is this error related with the database salt? Should I change the /var/www/html/moodle/auth/db/auth.php to reformat the password?

#### Versions etc.

- Moodle: 3.2.2+ (Build: 20170324).
- Moodle database: Postgresql 9.6.5.

The external database that I wanna connect: Oracle.

- Php:5.6.32.
- Ubuntu 16.

#### Screenshots

db_enabled.png

[image: db_enabled.png]

test_enabled.png

[image: test_enabled.png]

result_error.png

[image: result_error.png]

P.S.
Want to share some progress, I have changed the settings like this,

result_error.png

[image: result_error.png]
added apostrophe  in username and password field,  no the database error is gone, but still can't log in with the external database credentials,  the database is md5 hash,  in old system(Moodle 2.9),  I have compared the code, noticed that there is some custom code in auth.php, some code working with salted formats.  Please help me if you have some experience with salted passwords.  Thanks.